# Unity 迷路ゲーム

Tags: c#, unity3d

非常に長いのですが、一向に解決しないので質問させてください。
迷路ゲームを参考書をもとにscriptを描いたのですが、

```
UnityException: Tag: sphere is not defined!
MazeAppScript.ReSet () (at Assets/MazeAppScript.cs:73)
MazeAppScript.Start () (at Assets/MazeAppScript.cs:19)
```

のエラーが出てしまいました。
`CreateSphere()`メソッドでタグは追加してるのですが、どうにもうまくいきません、恐縮ですがご指摘どうかお願いいたします。

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MazeAppScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private System.Random rnd;
    private bool endFlg = false;
    public int power = 100;
    public int gameTime = 300;
    private int playTime = 300;
    private int endTime = 300;
    public int mazeSize = 10;
    public float mazeLevel = 1;
    private int hiScore = 0;
    private bool toolFlg = false;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rnd = new System.Random (System.Environment.TickCount);
        LoadPref ();
        ReSet ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            toolFlg = !toolFlg; 
            if(!toolFlg){SavePref();}
        }
        if (endFlg) { return; }
        playTime = endTime - (int)Time.time;
        CheckTime ();
    }

    void OnGuI(){
        GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 100), "POWRE/TIME");
        GUI.Label (new Rect (20, 40, 80, 20), "power:" + power);
        GUI.Label (new Rect (20, 70, 80, 20), "TIME:" + playTime);
        if (toolFlg) {
            GUI.Box (new Rect(120,10,100,40),"Size");
            mazeSize = (int)(GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(130,30,80,20),
                                                  mazeSize,5f,30f));
            GUI.Box(new Rect(120,60,100,40),"Level");
            mazeLevel = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(130,30,80,20)
                                             ,mazeLevel,0,10f);
            GUI.Box(new Rect(120,110,100,50),"Restart");
            if(GUI.Button (new Rect(130,130,80,20),"DO-IT!")){
                ReSet();
            }


        }
    }

    void LoadPref(){
        int loadSize = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("mazeSize");
        mazeLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("mazeLevel");
        hiScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("hiScore");
        if (loadSize != 0) {
            mazeSize = loadSize;
        }
    }

    void SavePref(){
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("mazeSize", mazeSize);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("mazeLevel", mazeLevel);
    }

    void ReSet(){
        SavePref ();
        GameObject[] walls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ob_wall");
        foreach (GameObject obj in walls) {
            GameObject.Destroy(obj);        
        }
        GameObject[] sps = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("sphere");
        foreach (GameObject obj in sps) {
            GameObject.Destroy(obj);
        }
        GameObject.Find ("GUI Text").guiText.text = "";
        CreateMazeData ();
        CreateSphere ();
        power = 100;
        endTime = gameTime + (int)Time.time;
        toolFlg = false;
        endFlg = false;
    }

    void CreateMazeData(){
        int mazeW = mazeSize * 4 + 2;
        bool[,] fdata = new bool[mazeW, mazeW];
        for (int i = 0; i < mazeW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mazeW; i++) {
                if(i == 0 || i == (mazeW - 1)||
                   j == 0 || j == (mazeW - 1)){
                    fdata[i,j] = true;
                }else{
                    fdata[i,j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        int[,] arw = new int[,]{
            {0,-1},{0,1},{-1,0},{1,0}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < (mazeSize / 2)*(mazeSize / 2); i++) {
            while(true){
                int x = rnd.Next (1, mazeSize) * 4;
                int y = rnd.Next (1, mazeSize) * 4;
                int n = i % 4;
                fdata[x,y] = true;
                while(true){
                    x += arw[n,0];
                    y += arw[n,1];
                    if(fdata[x,y]){
                        break;
                    }else{
                        fdata[x,y] = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        int cp = mazeW / 2;
        fdata[cp,cp] = false;
        GameObject.Find("DefaultAvatar").transform.position = new Vector3(cp, 0, cp);
        CreateMaze (fdata);

        int [,] gdatas = new int[,]{
            {1,1},{1,mazeW},{mazeW - 2,1},{mazeW - 2 ,mazeW - 2}
        };
        int gn = rnd.Next (4);
        Vector3 goalpos = new Vector3 (gdatas [gn, 0], 1.5f, gdatas [gn, 1]);
        GameObject.Find ("goal").transform.position = goalpos;

    }
    void  CreateMaze(bool[,] data){
        int mazeW = mazeSize * 4 + 2;
        Texture txtr = (Texture)Resources.Load("Grass&Rock");
        for (int i = 0; i < mazeW; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < mazeW ; j++){        
                if(data[i,j]){
                    GameObject obj = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                    obj.tag = "ob_wall";
                    obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,2,1);
                    obj.transform.position = new Vector3(i,1,j);
                    obj.renderer.material.mainTexture = txtr;
                    obj.collider.isTrigger = true;
                    GameObject obj2 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                    obj2.tag = "ob_wall";
                    obj2.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.9f,0.9f,0.9f);
                    obj2.transform.position = new Vector3(i,1,j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void CreateSphere(){
        for (int i = 0; i < (mazeSize / 2); i++) {
            GameObject obj = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            obj.tag = "sphere";
            obj.renderer.material.color = new Color(1,0,0,0.5f);
            obj.renderer.material.shader = Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse");
            obj.AddComponent("Rigidbody");
            obj.transform.position = new Vector3(rnd.Next(mazeSize) * 4 + 2, 0, rnd.Next(mazeSize) * 4 + 1);
            obj.AddComponent("MazeSphereScript");
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnd(){
        return endFlg;
    }

    public void LossPower(int n){
        power -= n;
        if(power <= 0){
            power = 0;
            BadEnd();
        }
    }

    public void CheckTime(){
        if (playTime <= 0) {
            BadEnd();       
        }
    }

    public void BadEnd(){
        endFlg = true;
        int score = (int)(power * mazeLevel + playTime * mazeSize);
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find ("GUI TEXT");
        obj.guiText.color = Color.blue;
        obj.guiText.text = "GAME OVER" + "\n" + "SCORE:" + score;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("hiscore", 1);

    }

    public void GoodEnd(){
        endFlg = true;
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("GUI Text");
        int score = (int)(power * mazeLevel * 2 + playTime * mazeSize * 2);
        string msg = "CLEAR!!";
        obj.guiText.color = Color.yellow;
        if (score > hiScore) {
            hiScore = score;
            msg = "Hi-score";
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("hiScore", hiScore);
            obj.guiText.color = Color.red;
        }
        msg += "\n" + "SCORE:" + score;
        obj.guiText.text = msg;
    }
```

Comment: Tag managerからは追加しました？

Comment: `CreateSphere`の実行（L.79）がエラー発生箇所（L.73）より後にあるからだったりしませんか？

Comment: どの環境(Unityのバージョン)で試したのか記載したほうがいいと思います。Unity 5.1.3-f1で試したところ、他のエラーがでました。
再現できる方が回答はつきやすいと思います。

Comment: Shintaroさんが書かれているように、"sphere"というタグをつけていないために`GameObject[] sps = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("sphere");`でエラーが出ているように思います。

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄の皆様の意見にもあるように、タグマネージャーに"sphere"のタグが登録されていないからだと思われます。
　FindGameObjectsWithTag関数は登録されていないタグを引数として指定すると例外を発生させるようです。
　http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html
　
　Editor上でタグを追加するには、メニュー > Edit > Project Setting > Tags and Layers から設定できます。

Comment: さまざまな解答ありがとうございました。
おかげで解決いたしました、お礼申し上げます。